# RECAMAN'S SEQUENCE FOR 20132014th TERM

Tags: c++

[image]

here is my program i want to know is there any alternate mathematical logic to generate the result within 30 seconds upto a20132014th term ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#include<conio.h>
long int *a,i,j,t;

int main()
{
    //clrscr();
    //printf("%ld",sizeof(long long  int));
    printf("\n Enter the number of terms: ");
    scanf("%ld",&t);

    a=(long int*)malloc(t*sizeof(long int));
    *(a+0)=0;
    printf("\na0=%5ld",*(a+0));
    for(i=1;i<=t;i++) {
        if(*(a+i-1)-i>0) {
            for(j=0;j<i;j++) {
                if(*(a+j)==*(a+i-1)-i)
                    goto Deepak;
            }
            *(a+i)=*(a+i-1)-i;
        }
        else
            Deepak:
        *(a+i)=*(a+i-1)+i;
        printf("\na%ld= %5ld",i,*(a+i));
    }
    //printf("\na%ld= %5ld",i,*(a+i));

    free(a);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with your program as it is (besides it being just about unreadable)?

Comment: All results? Or only the last?

Comment: Also, what do you think will happen with the expression `*(a+i)` when `i == t`? (Oh, and `*(a+i)` is equivalent to `a[i]` just so you know).

Comment: Finally, there's *no* C++ specific code in the code you show, maybe change the tag to C instead?

Comment: *(a+i) is equivalent to a[i] and to get 20132014th term we have to go through a[0] first its value is dependent on previous position value i.e. 20132013th term so how can i generate the result within 30 seconds is there any shortest algorithm instead of using this method ?

Comment: This program runs indefinitely, i am using dev c++

Comment: Alex Tartan- there is no problem in my program i want shortest algorithm to terminate it within 30 seconds.....

Comment: @DEEPAKTAMBOLI Actually, I just wrote a program without any fancy algorithm, just 200MB buffer, which runs in less than 1 second on a 8 year old laptop. The result is 76913715.

Comment: @deviantfan-what is the previous(20132013th) term value can you tell me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't told us a memory limit, with a buffer of ~200MB, a straight-forward
"dumb" calculation is possible and won't need anything near 30sec on a modern computer.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const size_t vs = 200<<20;
    vector<char> v(vs);
    int value = 0;
    int index = 1;
    v[0] = 1;

    while(index < 20132014)
    {
        if((value - index) > 0 && !v[value - index])
        {
            value -= index;
        }
        else
        {
            value += index;
            if(value >= vs)
            {
                cout << "vector too small " << index << endl;
                return 0;
            }
        }
        index++;
        v[value] = 1;
    }

    cout << value << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The result for the 20132014th number is 76913715.
You can easily change the loop condition to get other indices.

Comment: @deviantfan- what will happen if you try to print all the result from a0 to a20132014, will you  just get output in a second on the console screen ?

Comment: @DEEPAKTAMBOLI No, the console implementation is way too slow for that (and since the shown line count in the console is limited, 20132014 lines won't be readable there). If you want all results, writing it to a file and viewing it later would be faster.

Comment: i want all results printed in the console screen will i get using my method ?

Comment: @DEEPAKTAMBOLI Repeat: You can't have all results in the console screen.

Comment: i have reached a6048842=8606075 on console screen it takes too long time more than 5 hours..... :(

Comment: @DEEPAKTAMBOLI Can't you read? I already told you twice that the console is way too slow and a file is better. And if you have a6048842 already, can you scoll up to a1? No? Right.

Comment: till a6048842  i have then why not for 20132014 it will help me to check the answers to know whether it is correct or not ?

Comment: @DEEPAKTAMBOLI No, it won't help you, because you can't verify 20mio numbers manually. And if 6mio takes 5 hours, 20mio takes about 17 hours. Have fun, I'm out.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RecamansSequence.html

    http://oeis.org/A005132

    http://oeis.org/A005132/b005132.txt

Comment: @deviantfan- could you please explain how 200 mb buffer is allocated to vector space and why 20 is placed after 200 in this line - const size_t vs = 200<<20; is it means 2^20 = 1048576*200=209715200(sizeof v)       and why to use char in  vector<char> v(vs); instead of using int. and in the line  v[value] = 1; in which position value is stored ? we have assigned 1 to vector v same doubt for  v[0] = 1; in zero position why you have assigned 1 ?   i also want to know about straight-forward
"dumb" calculation.

Comment: @DEEPAKTAMBOLI `200<<20` is a bit shift, mathematically the same as `200 * 2^20`, ie. the number of bytes in 200MB. In the vector `v`, I use each element only to store 0 or 1, no other values, so I don't need a 4byte int, a 1byte char is enough. (Strictly speaking each byte could hold 8 times 0 or 1, the 25MB are enough, but extracting single bits from bytes everytime is slower). The 1 "had that value already", 0 the opposite.

Comment: i cant understand why each element is used to store 0 or 1 instead of storing sequence value in it. my doubt is here  v[value] = 1;(why 1 is assigned to vector) what will happen if i use v[index]=value; ? where index=0,1,2,3,4,5..... and value = sequence value....

Comment: I could do it like `v[index]=value`, but then, if I want to check if some value x is contained in v, I'd have to search everything in v. What I'm doing is to have a variable for each possible value, and assign 0 or 1 if i have it. That way I just need to check one element of v to check if a certain index is contained. (That was a *question*, not a doubt)

Comment: the value which has just arrived no longer need anymore to next element in that value position you have assigned 1 to avoid duplication so apart from these elements will remain empty space will be considered as 0 filled in it. now the question is in the expression !v[value-index]  if it contained calculated value already it will return 0(false to enter else portion) if it is new one then it will return 1(true to enter if portion) in that way we are checking am i right or wrong ?

Comment: can i write it directly const size_t vs = 200<<20 as const size_t vs = 209715200 ; how much memory i can allocate to vector in c++ is there any memory limit  ?

Comment: @DEEPAKTAMBOLI Please look up such easy things yourself. Yes, you can write 209715200, the limits are a) the number [ob bytes] which can be stored in `size_t` and b) What your OS allows (which may change depending on how much memory is in use, where it is located, how big is the swap file etc.etc.etc.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it depents on your machine, how long the programm will run. I have implemented the sequence myself and ran a test with it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>


auto print_recaman(long int n)
-> void {
    auto known_values = std::unordered_set<long int>{};
    known_values.reserve(n);

    long int previous = 0;
    long int i = 0;
    for(; i < n; i++) {
        std::cout << i << ": " << previous << '\n';
        auto next = previous - n;
        previous = (next <= 0 || known_values.count(next) > 0) ? 
                   previous + n :
                   next;
    }
    std::cout << i << ": " << previous << std::endl;    
}

auto main(int, char**) -> int {
    print_recaman(20132014L);
}
```

The test on my laptop:

```
$ time ./a.out > /dev/null

real    0m3.945s
user    0m3.914s
sys     0m0.031s
```

Comment: @cdonat- this code is not compiled in dev c++ in which version you have compiled ?

Comment: The code compile fine with `g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp` on a Linux system, though the code should be portable. Have you switched on C++11 support? I use C++11 specific syntax.

Comment: i dont have a linux system i am using window 7 OS ; dev c++ IDE

Comment: Just switch on C++11 support on your compiler. Microsofts compiler does support that as well.